# How do I override onInterceptTouchEvent after initializing a ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, viewgroup, intercept, ontouch

I've been reading everything I can find about this `onInterceptTouchEvent` but I can't seem to figure it out.

My code is like this

```
ViewGroup layer = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.layer);
```

..then some other stuff that works all fine.

How do I override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` for my `ViewGroup layer`? All I find is examples of custom classes extending `ViewGroup` or is that perhaps the only way?

The reason for this is that I need this `ViewGroup` to execute first in a very fragmented UI.

Any response is appreciated!

Comment: follow "custom classes extending ViewGroup" way

Comment: Sadly that is not an option I think. This ViewGroup is used by too many instances and they crash when being cast to MyViewGroup (my own implementation).

Comment: there is no other way, sorry